# Is creating a Linux Shared Library from Visual Studio 2017 Possible?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I was wondering if it's possible to create a shared library for Linux from within Visual Studio 2017?

Or would I have to develop on Linux and compile for Windows instead?

Thanks!

Comment: The potential dupe is now 7 years old. Nothing has happened since then?

Comment: Well the new way maybe run gcc/clang insider docker instead of a cross compiler.

Comment: Yes. Use this : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/03/30/visual-c-for-linux-development/
You'll need a Linux system with `gcc` etc. installed but it can be a VM or WSL (no need for another box) and you'll work entirely with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual studio can't build linux library with its built in toolchain, so you need an [extern build system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy.aspx).

You have two option for the external toolchain:

1. [cross compiler](http://wiki.osdev.org/GCC_Cross-Compiler)
2. [docker](https://blog.kitware.com/try-out-the-latest-gcc-with-docker/)

cross compiler is more suited for clean/freestanding environment. If your code rely on certain 3rd party libraries (and your target linux is compatible) it might be more convenient to use docker.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 can run external tools, so if you have a compiler that will generate Linux code while running on Windows you can do it.

If you have a Windows computer and a Linux computer in the same network, you can also set up Visual Studio on the Windows computer to run tools on the Linux computer.